# Need output in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have input like below here it is having two columns..one is target and one is reference...Here target may have one or more references i need to show all in one table

**Table**

```
Col1    col2
A        B
A        c
A        D
E        F
```

**Expected Result**

```
Col1    col2
A        B
A        c
A        D
B        A
C        A
D        A
E        F
F        E
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select col1, col2
From tbl
Union
Select col2, col1
From tbl
```